# How can i web scrape information from this website in R?

Tags: r, web-scraping, socrata, soda

This website http://a810-bisweb.nyc.gov/bisweb/bispi00.jsp is for searching nyc building application information. Under the "Application Searches" section, there is "BIS Job Number:", so the information I want to extract is from the new page after I enter a job number and then click "go".

For example, from the dataset
https://data.cityofnewyork.us/Housing-Development/DOB-Job-Application-Filings/ic3t-wcy2, I pick job number 220286232, and then go to the first website, put the number in "BIS Job Number:" and click go. Now I get a new page
. The information i want is "Applicant of Record Information" (including applicant contact information).

I'm stuck here. How can I extract these applicant information under each job number?

I am very new to web scraping. I learned how I can extract information from entire page by using rvest, but I'm not familiar with web scraping across different websites.

Thank you.

Update: I tried to use Socrata API, but I found the applicant contact information doesn't have their own API fields.If there is no API field for the information (but other information on that page has fields), does it mean I can't use API to solve this problem?

Thank you!

Comment: rvest has a couple functions for handling light forms, but you may need to escalate to RSelenium or [splashr](https://github.com/hrbrmstr/splashr) to grab the source if JavaScript needs to be run first. Once you've got the HTML, you can use rvest to parse it.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am trying to see if these two packages can help.

Answer (score 0):

On that [page](https://data.cityofnewyork.us/Housing-Development/DOB-Job-Application-Filings/ic3t-wcy2), top right, click on the "API" tab. A new modal dialog box will pop up "Access this Dataset via SODA API", copy the link, in this case
https://data.cityofnewyork.us/resource/rvhx-8trz.json .
This is an URL which provides the data directly in the machine-readable JSON format. But only 1000 records at a time will be fetched.

So maybe add appropriate `$offset` parameters. See the [Socrata documentation](https://dev.socrata.com/docs/queries/). The City of New York seems to use this software for their Open Data platform.

Maybe call them this way in your R script :

```
https://data.cityofnewyork.us/resource/rvhx-8trz.json?$offset=0
https://data.cityofnewyork.us/resource/rvhx-8trz.json?$offset=500
https://data.cityofnewyork.us/resource/rvhx-8trz.json?$offset=1000
https://data.cityofnewyork.us/resource/rvhx-8trz.json?$offset=...
```

(untested for higher offsets)

Use jsonlite for converting JSON into R data frames.

Comment: Thank you, knb. I tried to use API before, but the problem is in this https://data.cityofnewyork.us/resource/rvhx-8trz.json, there is no applicant contact information (Email or phone number). It only has license number, applicants' names and their professional titles, which needs to be extract under "Applicant of Record Information" as i showed in the example above. Thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: maybe the API offers a different endpoint, or a different parameterization to get also the contact-info data? I didn't look any deeper into it.

Comment: I didn't see they provide API fields for contact info. If they didn't provide in this dataset https://data.cityofnewyork.us/Housing-Development/DOB-Job-Application-Filings/ic3t-wcy2, does it mean there is no related API field I can find?

Comment: A while ago I ran across [an R package made by the City of Chicago for Socrata APIs](https://github.com/Chicago/RSocrata)